# Synchronising Session/Cookie with FormsAuthentication cookie

Tags: asp.net, session, forms-authentication, session-cookies

I know what you're thinking...someone else has made this mistake!

I'm working on a site that uses the standard .NET membership provider. User's can create an account and login, however they can also checkout (purchase goods) without physically creating an account. In this instance, the user is still creating a .NET membership account, however they are not being logged in using the standard FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie. This seems to be ok - unless the user (who hasnt created an account sits idle for an hour they are not prompted to re-enter their details). When a user checks out, an account is created and their UserProviderKey is stored in a session.

The problem comes with users that have created an account. The checkout process depends on the existence of the session object. Sometimes, the session may have timed out, but the FormsAuthentication cookie still exists - this throws the logic into some problems.

So, i understand that I've probably made a mistake putting something in the session object and then depending on it, but what are the alternatives? Are cookies any better?

Thanks in advance

Al

Answer (score 0):

No need to reinvent the wheel.  Asp.net supports the concept of an anonymous profile that can then be optionally migrated to a registered user.  Is this possible with your application?

> Support for anonymous profiles is not enabled by default, so you must explicitly enable it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewfkf772.aspx

Comment: Mmmm, I didnt think of that. However, where is the anonymous profile info stored? Is it still in the aspnet_Users tables?